# Cannot use Stored Procedure on Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF5, database first, VS 2012 update 2

In designer, I right click and select `Update model from database`, select a stored procedure and save the project, rebuild, then I try to use the stored procedure as a method on the code but it's not recognized.

The stored procedure is shown in Model Browser under `MyModel.Store/Stored Procedures / Functions`
And also under `MyModel/Function Imports`

Code is generated on `MyModel.Context.cs` (under `.edmx`), but not in `MyModelEntities.cs`, and I think that's the problem.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try deleting the stored procedure and add it again.

Comment: What is MyModelEntities.cs? It will be generated only in the Context class and you must call it using that class.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: I have a class file MyModelEntities.cs which define a **public class MyModelEntities : DbContext**. And also, under MyModel.edmx/MyModel.Context.tt/MyModel.Context.cs is defined a **public partial class MyModelEntities : DbContext**

Comment: I have removed MyModelEntities.cs from the project and now is working fine, probably I have mistakenly copied the class from another project

Answer (score 0):

Just removed `MyModelEntities.cs` from the project and now is working fine.

There should be only the Context class (`MyModel.Context.cs` file)